# Receber vetor do usuário em C

Tags: c, array

Olá, pessoal. Preciso de ajuda para receber um vetor de inteiros (separados por espaços) do usuário. Eis o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Observacoes:
1, se a ordem nao e decrescente
-1, se a ordem nao e crescente
0, se nao ha ordem
99 se for constante*/

//declaracao de variaveis globais
int t; //tamanho do vetor
int* v; //ponteiro para vetor de inteiros

//prototipo funcao
int verificaOrdem(int* v);

int main(){
  //Receber vetor de tamanho 4 como input

  int rc = verificaOrdem(v); //chamada de funcao
  printf("\n Retorno da funcao verificaOrdem: %d \n", rc);

  return 0;  /*Isso serve para informar ao compilador que ocorreu tudo certo com a função main(). Se main retornasse um outro valor diferente de 0 haveria um problema em sua execução, que seria informada ao compilador*/
}

int verificaOrdem(int* v){
  bool aumentando = false;
  bool diminuindo = false;
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i ){
    if(v[i] > v[i+1]) diminuindo = true;
    if(v[i] < v[i+1]) aumentando = true;
    if(aumentando && diminuindo) return 0;
  }
  if(aumentando) return 1;
  if(diminuindo) return -1;
  return 99;
}
```

Comment: Para ler `n` digitos, você precisa saber `n`. Caso contrário, caso esteja fazendo algo voltado a eventos (por exemplo, até acabar o arquivo/_streaming_ de dados), você captura o evento e diz que terminou o vetor. Você pode fazer o processamento de descobrir se o vetor está crescente ou decrescente sem precisar armazenar mais do que dois dados da entrada e os booleanos de ordem.

Comment: Pronto, Jefferson, fiz as correções apontadas. Minha dúvida está em receber um vetor de tamanho 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso até que deu um trabalhinho para fazer, mas está aqui:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/*Observacoes:
1, se a ordem nao e decrescente
-1, se a ordem nao e crescente
0, se nao ha ordem
99 se for constante*/

void separarInteiros(int *destino, int tamanho, char *entrada);
int verificaOrdem(int* v, int tamanho);

int main() {
  int v[4];

  char entrada[100];
  fgets(entrada, 100, stdin);
  separarInteiros(v, 4, entrada);
  int rc = verificaOrdem(v, 4);
  printf("\n Retorno da funcao verificaOrdem: %d \n", rc);

  return 0;
}

void separarInteiros(int *destino, int tamanho, char *entrada) {
  char *resto = entrada;
  for (int contador = 0; contador < tamanho; contador++) {
    int final = 0;
    while (1) {
      if (resto[final] == '\0' && final == 0) return;
      if (resto[final] == ' ' || resto[final] == '\0') {
        resto[final] = '\0';
        if (final != 0) destino[contador] = atoi(resto);
        resto = &(resto[final + 1]);
        if (final != 0) {
          final = 0;
          break;
        }
      } else {
        final++;
      }
    }
  }
}

int verificaOrdem(int* v, int tamanho) {
  bool aumentando = false;
  bool diminuindo = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < tamanho - 1; ++i) {
    if (v[i] > v[i + 1]) diminuindo = true;
    if (v[i] < v[i + 1]) aumentando = true;
    if (aumentando && diminuindo) return 0;
  }
  if (aumentando) return 1;
  if (diminuindo) return -1;
  return 99;
}
```

Para ler a entrada, usei a função `fgets`.

A função `separarInteiros` é a responsável por fazer a mágica acontecer. O `for` percorre de 0 a 3, cada iteração para montar um número. O `while` vai percorrendo as letras até achar um espaço vazio, o substitui por `\0`, isolando uma palavra do resto da entrada. Então, a função `atoi` é usada para converter a palavra em um número e a análise segue com o restante da entrada.

Havia um bug na sua função `verificaOrdem`. Ela percorria os itens de 0 até 3. Isso significa que o item 3 seria comparado com o item 4, que já está fora do array. A solução é ir do 0 ao 3 (ou no caso do código que postei, de 0 até `tamanho - 1`).

Comment: Obrigado, Victor Stafusa. Pode me explicar melhor essa função separarInteiros? Não entendi essa variável tamanho. Tamanho do que? Também gostaria de entender o ponteiro resto

Comment: O `resto` é o "resto da entrada". O `while` funciona picando a string em pedaços substituindo os espaços por `'\0'`. A cada iteração, ela é picada em duas, uma contendo o número a ser analisado e outra contendo o resto da entrada. Esse `tamanho` é o tamanho do array representado pelo ponteiro `destino`.